# Python Label Printer Program

Tags: python

I want to print two labels that have the same numbers on them. I am using `ZPL`. I have already made my print format in `ZPL` and it works properly. I am trying to print a data range. For example:

"What is the first number in the range?" *User inputs 100*
"What is the second number in the range?" *User inputs 120*

I would then get 40 labels in order.
I then want it to export that data into a notepad file and then print it to my default printer. My problem is that to print with `ZPL` I have to "tag" my data range with my `ZPL` code. I cant figure out how to get my data range to go into my print statement correctly. Please help. Thank you in advance!

```py
import os
import sys


start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))


with open('TestFile.txt', 'a') as sys.stdout:
   print('^XA')
   print('^PQ2')
for labelRange in range(start, end + 1):
     print('^FO185,50^A0,300^FD')(labelRange, end = " ")('^FS') 
#print('\n')
print('^XZ')

os.startfile("C:/Users/joe.smith/desktop/TestFile.txt", "print")

exit()
```

Comment: please show your efforts and provide a [mre]

Comment: that is invalid syntax right there, do you understand how `print` function works? works like any regular function except it is a built-in

Comment: If the user inputs 100 and 120, why does that mean you print 40 labels?

Comment: @khelwood because I have it to print every label twice in my ZPL code.

Comment: If you print labels 100 to 120 inclusive, twice each, that's 42 labels.

Comment: @Matiiss I guess not? That's why I asked for help?

Comment: zebra programming language is not anything anyone will know well. Provide a sample of a working ZPL file for say label 110 and 111 both printed twice. Then someone can help you with how to output that file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Programming_Language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is something to get you started, but I doubt it is complete. You will need to provide a valid ZPL file for making the changes.

I also made the program use fixed numbers for now and so it just runs and outputs.You can change it back once you have it working.

```
start = 110
end = 111

notepad = ''
# these are header lines that go once (if windows you might need \r\n instead of \n)
notepad += '^XA\n'
notepad += '^PQ2\n'
for label in range(start, end + 1):
    # use f-strings
    notepad += f'^FO185,50^A0,300^FD{label}^FS\n'
    # if you need some of those other numbers to increment
    # then setup a counter and do the math here inside the f-string
    notepad += f'^FO185,50^A0,300^FD{label}^FS\n'
notepad += '^XZ\n'
# with open('tf.txt', 'w') as sys.stdout:
#     print(notepad)
print(notepad)
exit()
```

outputs:

```
^XA
^PQ2
^FO185,50^A0,300^FD110^FS
^FO185,50^A0,300^FD110^FS
^FO185,50^A0,300^FD111^FS
^FO185,50^A0,300^FD111^FS
^XZ
```